# Strip() function with readlines()

Tags: python, strip

With the strip() function the \n does not strip and instead changes the string (I don't know how to describe it, test for yourself)

```
lines = []
line = str(pw.readlines())
print(line)
x = line.strip("\n")
x = line.strip("\t")
lines.append(x)
print(lines)enter code here
```

edit:

here is the output I get from debugging:

Original string:
`['pqrm \n', 'google \n', '8']`

After I try to strip it I get:
`["['pqrm \\n', 'google \\n', '8']"]`

Comment: If you want us to test it you need to provide the problematic input. And you can describe it by posting the actual and expected output and explain the difference.

Comment: Besides that, you are converting the list of lines to one long string, and call `strip()` on that. ``strip()` removes only leading and trailing whitespaces. Iterate over the list and call `strip()` one by one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: 1) Do you pass the parameters `'\r'` and `'\n'` on purpose? Why not use the default whitespaces, i.e., call with no parameters? 2) When calling `str(pw.readlines())` you're turning the list into a string that represents a serialized list, it will start with the `[` character and end with the `]` character, so `strip` won't do the work you're trying to do. You should use list comprehensions and strip every line in the list separately: `lines = [l.strip() for l in pw.readlines()]`

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the list of values as a string, instead of each value one by one. So try this...

```
lines = []
for line in pw.readlines():
    x = line.strip("\n").strip("\t")
    lines.append(x)

print(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use re.sub, to get rid of newlines, tabs, spaces.

```
import re

st = "['pqrm \n', 'google \n', '8']"

print(re.sub(r'[\n\t\s]+','', st))

['pqrm','google','8']
```